# how to select an SDR stick remotely from gqrx via soapysdr

Tags: rtl-sdr

I have a raspberry pi 3b on my roof (in a plastic box) with two SDR sticks attached to it.
On the raspberry pi the "soapysdr" program runs.

```
root@antenne:/# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T

root@antenne:/# rtl_fm -f 123M -d 1 | more
Found 2 device(s):
  0:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN: 00000001
  1:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN:
```

Now from my laptop running GQRX, I can connect to the first SDR module attached to the rpi by using the following device string:

```
soapy=0,driver=remote,remote:driver=rtlsdr
```

My question now is: how do I select the second device? (from within gqrx)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for days for an answer for this problem and then suddenly I realised it is quite simple:

Use rtl_eeprom to give the the stick without serial a serial number:

```
rtl_eeprom -d 1 -s 66666666
```

Then it is only a matter of adding ",serial=66666666" to the device string in gqrx:

```
soapy=0,driver=remote,remote:driver=rtlsdr,serial=66666666
```